# MarkerCluster Animation for OpenLayers2 with Lines

Tags: style, openlayers-2, clustering, vector-layer

I would like to implement a MarkerCluster-Animation in OpenLayers2 but could need some advice where to start.
If you have a look at this (OpenLayers2-)webpage:

http://spielplatz-radar.de/#position/M52165100

you can get an idea what I want to do.

If two markers are lying too close to each other and you do a mouseover they will be moved away from their "real" position and a line is drawn to still show where this marker has its "real" position.
So it's more or less something like the MarkerClusterPlugin of Leaflet.

The sourcecode of this webpage is pretty complicated as it uses backbone views so i find it hard to find the important parts and implement this animation in an app that doesn't use backbone.js

Can anybody give me some advices where to start?

Image1: markers spread as they lie too close to each other

[image: Markers spread]

Image2: same markers at a higher zoom level: not spread anymore as the icons don't overlap anymore:

[image]

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use OpenLayers? Leaflet has a very nice Marker Cluster package,

Comment: yes it has to be OpenLayers what I already regret as obviously no one of the developers has a clue how to realize such a functionality